# Docker cannot acces registry from openshift

Tags: docker, openshift, rhel

Here is my whole scenario.

I have a RHEL 7.1 vmware image, with the corporate proxy properly configured, accessing stuff over http or https works properly.

Installed docker-engine, and added the HTTP_PROXY setting to `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`. I can verify the proxy setting is picked up by executing:

`sudo systemctl show docker --property Environment`

which will print:

`Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.mycompany.com:myport/` with real values of course.

Pulling and running docker images works correctly this way.

The goal is to work with the binary distribution of **openshift-origin**. I downloaded the binaries, and started setting up things as per the walkthrough page on github:

> https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/sample-app/README.md

Starting openshift seems to work as I can:
* login via the openshift cli
* create a new project
* even access the web console

But when I try to create an app in the project (also via the cli):

`oc new-app centos/ruby-22-centos7~https://github.com/openshift/ruby-hello-world.git`

It fails:

`error: can't look up Docker image "centos/ruby-22-centos7": Internal error occurred: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 52.71.246.213:443: connection refused`

I can access (without authentication though) this endpoint via the browser on the VM or via WGET.

Hence I believe DOCKER fails to pick up the proxy settings. After some searching I also fear if there are IPTABLES settings missing. Referring to:

> https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/articles/networking/

But I don't know if I should fiddle with the IPTABLES settings, should not Docker figure that out itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your HTTPS_PROXY environment property.

Comment: It turns out that it was in fact the proxy. So the problem was that I ran openshift with a user who had no idea of the proxy settings. When I claimed the proxy configuration is correct I was wrong, because it was only correct for my user.